# What is Mathematica's equivalent to Maple's collect with distributed option?

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-manipulation, maple

Given a polynomial in $x,y$, I want to collect on $x,y$ and any products of these also. As given using Maple's [collect](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=collect) with the distributed option.

Currently Mathematica will collect on $x$ then collect on $y$. But this is not what I want.

An example will explain. Given this

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
eq = -x^6*y*c[5] + x^6*y*c[9] - x^5*y^2*c[4] + x^5*y^2*c[10] - 
  x^6*c[5] + x^6*c[9] - 2*x^5*y*c[4] + 2*x^5*y*c[10] + x^4*y^2*c[5] - 
  x^4*y^2*c[9] - x^5*c[4] - x^5*c[6] + x^5*c[8] + x^4*y*c[1] - 
  x^4*y*c[3] - 2*x^4*y*c[7] + 2*x^3*y^2*c[2] - 2*x^3*y^2*c[4] - 
  x^3*y^2*c[8] + x^2*y^3*c[3] - x*y^4*c[4] + x^4*c[1] - x^4*c[3] - 
  2*x^3*y*c[6] + 3*x^2*y^2*c[1] - 2*x^2*y^2*c[3] - y^4*c[3]
```

If I just collect on `x,y` this is the result

```
 Collect[eq,{x,y}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

What I want is to collect on anything involving $x,y$ or products of these. This is what Maple's distributed option allows:

```
eq := -x^6*y*c[5] + x^6*y*c[9] - x^5*y^2*c[4] + x^5*y^2*c[10] - x^6*c[5] + x^6*c[9] 
 - 2*x^5*y*c[4] + 2*x^5*y*c[10] + x^4*y^2*c[5] - x^4*y^2*c[9] - x^5*c[4] - x^5*c[6] 
 + x^5*c[8] + x^4*y*c[1] - x^4*y*c[3] - 2*x^4*y*c[7] + 2*x^3*y^2*c[2] - 2*x^3*y^2*c[4] 
 - x^3*y^2*c[8] + x^2*y^3*c[3] - x*y^4*c[4] + x^4*c[1] - x^4*c[3] - 2*x^3*y*c[6] 
 + 3*x^2*y^2*c[1] - 2*x^2*y^2*c[3] - y^4*c[3];
 collect(eq,[x,y],distributed)
```

[image]

You see the difference. The reason I wanted this, is to be able to set equations of all coefficients of anything thing that has $x$ or $y$ in order to solve for the unknowns $c_i$.  The output given by Maple makes this much easier.

Here is another example to make it more clear

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
eq=(-x^3)*a[1] - x*y*a[1] - x^4*a[2] - 2*x^2*y*a[2] - y^2*a[2] + (-x^2 + y)*(a[0] + x*a[1] + y*a[2]) + x^3*b[1] + x*y*b[1] + x^2*b[2] - x*(b[0] + y*b[1] + x*b[2]) == 0
Collect[eq,{x,y}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Compare to

```
eq:=(-x^3)*a[1] - x*y*a[1] - x^4*a[2] - 2*x^2*y*a[2] - y^2*a[2] + (-x^2 + y)*(a[0] + x*a[1] + y*a[2]) + x^3*b[1] + x*y*b[1] + x^2*b[2] - x*(b[0] + y*b[1] + x*b[2]) = 0;
collect(eq,[x,y],distributed)
```

[image]

The question is: How to obtain the same output as Maple's in this case?

Comment: Thanks both for great answers, I wish I can accept both.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
CoefficientRules[eq, {x, y}] /. ({a_, b_} -> c_) :> c x^a y^b // Total
```

Generalize it to a function:

```
maplecollect[a_ == b_, varlst_List] := maplecollect[a - b, varlst] == 0
maplecollect[poly_, varlst_List] := 
 CoefficientRules[poly, varlst] /. (lhs_ -> rhs_) :> rhs Times @@ (varlst^lhs) // 
  Total    

eq = -x^6*y*c[5] + x^6*y*c[9] - x^5*y^2*c[4] + x^5*y^2*c[10] - x^6*c[5] + x^6*c[9] - 
   2*x^5*y*c[4] + 2*x^5*y*c[10] + x^4*y^2*c[5] - x^4*y^2*c[9] - x^5*c[4] - x^5*c[6] +
    x^5*c[8] + x^4*y*c[1] - x^4*y*c[3] - 2*x^4*y*c[7] + 2*x^3*y^2*c[2] - 
   2*x^3*y^2*c[4] - x^3*y^2*c[8] + x^2*y^3*c[3] - x*y^4*c[4] + x^4*c[1] - x^4*c[3] - 
   2*x^3*y*c[6] + 3*x^2*y^2*c[1] - 2*x^2*y^2*c[3] - y^4*c[3];

maplecollect[eq, {x, y}]
(* 
x^2 y^2 (3 c[1] - 2 c[3]) + x^4 (c[1] - c[3]) + x^2 y^3 c[3] - y^4 c[3] - 
 x y^4 c[4] - 2 x^3 y c[6] + x^4 y (c[1] - c[3] - 2 c[7]) + 
 x^3 y^2 (2 c[2] - 2 c[4] - c[8]) + x^5 (-c[4] - c[6] + c[8]) + 
 x^4 y^2 (c[5] - c[9]) + x^6 (-c[5] + c[9]) + x^6 y (-c[5] + c[9]) + 
 x^5 y^2 (-c[4] + c[10]) + x^5 y (-2 c[4] + 2 c[10]) *)
   
eq2 = (-x^3)*a[1] - x*y*a[1] - x^4*a[2] - 2*x^2*y*a[2] - 
    y^2*a[2] + (-x^2 + y)*(a[0] + x*a[1] + y*a[2]) + x^3*b[1] + x*y*b[1] + x^2*b[2] -
     x*(b[0] + y*b[1] + x*b[2]) == 0;

maplecollect[eq2, {x, y}]
(* -x^2 a[0] + y a[0] - x^4 a[2] - 3 x^2 y a[2] - x b[0] + 
  x^3 (-2 a[1] + b[1]) == 0 *)
```

Answer (score 11):

#### Update 2:

An alternative way to define a function that works like Maple's collect using [`CoefficientRules`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoefficientRules.html) + [`FromCoefficientRules`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FromCoefficientRules.html):

```
collectLikeMaple = FromCoefficientRules[CoefficientRules@##, #2] &;

{collectLikeMaple[eq, {x, y}] == 
   Collect[eq, {x, y}, $distributed],
 (collectLikeMaple[First@SubtractSides@eq2, {x, y}] == 0) == 
  Collect[eq2, {x, y}, $distributed],
 collectLikeMaple[eq3, {x, y, z}] == 
  Collect[eq3, {x, y, z}, $distributed]}
```

> ```
>  {True, True, True}
> ```

Alternatively, use [`TagSetDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagSetDelayed.html)
to add an argument to `Collect` that makes it behave like Maple's `collect`:

```
ClearAll[doItLikeMappleDoes]
doItLikeMappleDoes /: 
 Collect[p_Plus, vl_List, h_ : Identity, doItLikeMappleDoes] := 
 FromCoefficientRules[MapAt[h, {All, 2}] @ CoefficientRules[p, vl], vl]

doItLikeMappleDoes /: 
 Collect[e_Equal, vl_List, h_ : Identity, doItLikeMappleDoes] := 
 Collect[First @ SubtractSides @ e, vl, h, doItLikeMappleDoes] == 0
```

***Examples:***

```
{Collect[eq, {x, y}, doItLikeMappleDoes] == 
  Collect[eq, {x, y}, $distributed],
 Collect[eq2, {x, y}, doItLikeMappleDoes] == 
  Collect[eq2, {x, y}, $distributed],
 Collect[eq3, {x, y, z}, Simplify, doItLikeMappleDoes] == 
  Collect[eq3, {x, y, z}, Simplify, $distributed]}
```

> ```
>  {True, True, True}
> ```

#### Update:

Use [`TagSetDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagSetDelayed.html) to add an argument to `Collect` to make it behave like Maple `collect`

```
$distributed /: Collect[e_, vl_List, h___, $distributed] := 
 Collect[e, 
 {Splice @ MapApply[Times] @ Reverse @ Subsets[#, {2, Length @ #}],
  Splice @ #} & @ Map[#^_. &] @ vl, h]
```

***Examples:***

```
Collect[eq, {x, y}, $distributed]
```

[image]

```
Collect[eq2, {x, y}, $distributed]
```

[image]

```
eq3 = Expand[(a + b x + c y + d  z + e y x + y z + y^2)^2]

Collect[eq3, {x, y, z}, Simplify, $distributed]
```

[image]

#### Original answer:

Use a pattern in the second argument of `Collect`:

```
Collect[eq, {x^_. y^_., x^_., y^_.}]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

```
Collect[ExpandAll @ eq2, {x^_. y^_., x^_., y^_.}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this does not produce the desired output all the time. For example, trying on the second example I gave, it gives this  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPML2.png)  which is not same as Maple's output. May be it could be modified to do so?

Comment: I think your most recent update changed thing too much. Now it no longer matches Maple. What you had before seemed better, which is `Collect[ExpandAll@eq, x^_. y^_.]`. Here is screen shot showing the difference ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZy3u.png)

Comment: @Nasser, please try the updated version.

Comment: Yes, much better version now.

Comment: `ExpandAll` can be taken away :) .

Comment: @xzczd, thank you again. Updated.

Answer (score 9):

Another way:

```
Plus @@ MonomialList[eq, {x, y}]

(*
x^2 y^2 (3 c[1] - 2 c[3]) + x^4 (c[1] - c[3]) +
 x^2 y^3 c[3] - y^4 c[3] - x y^4 c[4] - 2 x^3 y c[6] +
 x^4 y (c[1] - c[3] - 2 c[7]) + x^3 y^2 (2 c[2] - 2 c[4] - c[8]) +
 x^5 (-c[4] - c[6] + c[8]) + x^4 y^2 (c[5] - c[9]) +
 x^6 (-c[5] + c[9]) + x^6 y (-c[5] + c[9]) +
 x^5 y^2 (-c[4] + c[10]) + x^5 y (-2 c[4] + 2 c[10])
*)
```

Or, 2nd OP's example, two solutions:

```
Plus @@ MonomialList[#, {x, y}] & /@ eq
Plus @@ MonomialList[Subtract @@ eq, {x, y}] == 0

(* both:
-x^2 a[0] + y a[0] - x^4 a[2] - 3 x^2 y a[2] - x b[0] + 
  x^3 (-2 a[1] + b[1]) == 0
*)
```

Comment: `Total @` instead of `Plus @@` depending on one's taste. (Not a packed array, so no big difference.)

Comment: Oh, I didn't know `MonomialList` collect the coefficient! (+1 of course. )

Comment: Simpler, nice! (+1)

Answer (score 7):

Another idea is to use a wrapper around the coefficients, and then expanding:

```
DistributedCollect[a_, b_, h_:Identity] := Activate @ Expand @ Collect[a, b, Inactive[h]]
```

Example:

```
eq:=-x^6*y*c[5]+x^6*y*c[9]-x^5*y^2*c[4]+x^5*y^2*c[10]-x^6*c[5]+x^6*c[9]-2*x^5*y*c[4]+2*x^5*y*c[10]+x^4*y^2*c[5]-x^4*y^2*c[9]-x^5*c[4]-x^5*c[6]+x^5*c[8]+x^4*y*c[1]-x^4*y*c[3]-2*x^4*y*c[7]+2*x^3*y^2*c[2]-2*x^3*y^2*c[4]-x^3*y^2*c[8]+x^2*y^3*c[3]-x*y^4*c[4]+x^4*c[1]-x^4*c[3]-2*x^3*y*c[6]+3*x^2*y^2*c[1]-2*x^2*y^2*c[3]-y^4*c[3];

DistributedCollect[eq, {x, y}]
```

> x^2 y^2 (3 c[1] - 2 c[3]) + x^4 (c[1] - c[3]) + x^2 y^3 c[3] - y^4 c[3] -
> x y^4 c[4] - 2 x^3 y c[6] + x^4 y (c[1] - c[3] - 2 c[7]) +
> x^3 y^2 (2 c[2] - 2 c[4] - c[8]) + x^5 (-c[4] - c[6] + c[8]) +
> x^4 y^2 (c[5] - c[9]) + x^6 (-c[5] + c[9]) + x^6 y (-c[5] + c[9]) +
> x^5 y^2 (-c[4] + c[10]) + x^5 y (-2 c[4] + 2 c[10])